# Keeping timezone while saving with Spring repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I try to save an object into the H2 database using the Spring repository. I need to keep the original timezone, but it's converted to the local zone.

I have an object with field `ZonedDateTime dateTime` and it's marked with `@Column(columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")`, so in H2 value saves with timezone. For saving I use repository `extends JpaRepository`, so just `jpaRepository.save(entity)`.

2019-10-04T15:59:50.869-04:00[America/New_York] become 2019-10-04T19:59:50.869+03:00[Europe/Moscow] what is inappropriate in my case.
Are there any properties to prevent converting to the local zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I don't think you can get this to work (i.e. TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE + JDBC driver + database + Hibernate/JPA).

So, what I would do:

- Save your timestamp in UTC.
- Store the user's timezone separately.
- If needed, show the user the timestamp according to his timezone.